# How to read data file with date in rows and hours in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've data with two parameters (T and P) that has an interval of 6 hours. The data has for each row a single day and several columns for the hours. Like this:

```
iiiii    dateday     Lon     Lat    T02 T08 T14 T20  P02     P08     P14     P20
51076   20130701    8808    4773    177 165 254 180 9209    9218    9218    9220
51076   20130702    8808    4773    156 164 254 250 9215    9214    9217    9213
51076   20130703    8808    4773    194 205 284 308 9213    9210    9209    9193
51076   20130704    8808    4773    228 199 246 230 9203    9218    9227    9224
51076   20130705    8808    4773    179 167 224 229 9222    9239    9231    9217
```

So for date `20130701` there are 4 measurements for `T` on hour `02`/`08`/`14` and `20` and likewise for `P`.

How can I read this data in pandas to get the dateindex in format `YYYYMMDDHH` with two parameters `T` and `P` as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read file line by line, skipping the first line:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
```

Then you should parse a line, if the format is always same for each line, you can simple `split` it and remove empty values:

```
        parsed = filter(None, line.split(' ')
```

After that you can access the dateday and T and P parameters, for example:

```
        print(parsed[1]) # dateday
        print(parsed[4]) # T02
        print(parsed[11]) # P20
```

After that, you can save the 'parsed' value into a list or dictionary, or use it immediatly in the loop